# Adding + between keywords PHP

Tags: php

In my tag cloud I have urls that look like this

- `../search.php?query=cat&select=all`
- `../search.php?query=the cat&select=all`

What I am trying to do is if the keyword is more than one word like so:

- `../search.php?query=the cat&select=all`

Put a `+` between the words like this

- `../search.php?query=the+cat&select=all`

My default search function uses the `+` in the searches performed by the form but I would also like my tag cloud to have the same thing. I am only doing this for looks. It works perfectly fine as is but I thought I would ask anyway. Can anyone help? this is what I am currently using for links in my tag cloud

```
echo " <a href='../search.php?query=$word&amp;select=all' target='rel' title='".($word)."'>".($word)."</a>";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function.

Comment: Not necessary - when it's extracted into $_REQUEST and $_GET, it'll be automatically decoded. You only need urldecode() if you're breaking up a URL by hand.

Comment: Thanks. Works perfect. Since you were the first to answer I will accept your answer when stackoverflow allows me to in a few minutes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`urlencode` & `urldecode` is just the function you require.

```
echo " <a href='../search.php?query=".urlencode($word)."&amp;select=all' target='rel' title='".($word)."'>".($word)."</a>";
```

and on the other page you can have `urldecode`

```
echo urldecode($_GET['query']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I appreciate it.